# What defines a Teradata "data definition statement"

Tags: database, teradata, tableau-api, volatile

The reason for my question is I have a SQL script which builds a result in a number of stages, using volatile tables (I don't have the permissions to create regular tables). I create my first volatile table to try and keep parts of the script quite modular, and then the second table uses the result set of the first, the third the second and then so on.

I'm then using Tableau to build a visualisation of my data, putting the `create volatile table` sections of the script in the Initial SQL portion, and then I'm just doing a `select` from the volatile table in my request. The problem is the Teradata ODBC client returns the error:

> 3576   Data definition not valid unless solitary

I don't have this issue every time I try this, so I'm wondering what it is that's prompting this to occur, so I'm wondering, what counts as a "data definition statement" in Teradata. Sometimes I use this approach and it works fine, others do not, and I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: Maybe a semi-colon needs to follow the create statement? Create table is definitely a DDL.

Answer (score 3):

DDL statements are obviously any `CREATE` or `DROP`, but also `COLLECT STATISTICS` and `DATABASE ...` commands.

Each DDL statement must be a individually commited = a request with a single statement = a standalone transaction.

If you have access to the QueryLog you might check the actual SQL sent to Teradata which caused that error.